# INSERT conflicted with FOREIGN KEY constraint (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_member_patient_member_status" (of table x). The conflict occurred in database "D" table "y".

I want to INSERT the STATUS field of table y into table x but it gives this error because table x has this above mentioned FK (and table y does not have it as a PK or FK or any field for that matter)

As I understand it it couldnt reference it? I do not have rights to change FK's and PK's on system.
What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Need you to explain more about your issue, especially, the FK definition, looks like it is not between X and Y, it should be between X and some table else. Please check the FK definition, if you don't have permission, then you need to apply for permission to understand your database, update your query accordingly. I guess you need to insert the status value from table Y, first to another table other than X, which saves the status dictionary. Sorry, no permission to edit comment, so post this as 'answer'.